# enter special characters (accents) in a windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a MS Paint like application and we allow the user to enter text as well. Now a requirement is to allow the user to enter accents and other special characters.

I understand that we can show the charmap.exe from within the application and allow the user to copy the character and the paste it in the text box used to enter the text. However, we would like the ability where user selects the character and it is entered in the text box.

So is implementing a dialog with the character set the only option ? And if it is the only option, is there a standard way to implement this.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: cant the user just write the text with the keyboard? i must be missing something

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything. Typically the user will have a keyboard that lets them enter the characters that they need for their language. For some languages they will use a system provided IME but again you need to do nothing special to support this.

Comment: Yes, we do not need to do anything special however,so I have went ahead and implemented a dialog showing some special characters so that the user gets a ability to enter characters without knowing their code or using another exe like charmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a form like you suggested, or you let the user enter the characters from the keyboard. Special characters not on the keyboard can be entered using the Alt key and the number for that character, such as Alt-225 for ß. As David said, you generally don't need to do anything since most people have keyboards that support the characters they use.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need to do anything. The user's operating system and keyboard will be configured to allow him to enter all the necessary characters, possibly via IME.

As a last resort, one can use numeric codes by typing ALT+[code].